# PHP - Securing POST URLs from iOS App

Tags: php, ios, objective-c, post

Please forgive me for my ignorance in advance, I'm a rookie when it comes to PHP. An iOS app I'm experimenting with has an already-built PHP API that makes requests as such:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://beta.myapp.com/api/addUser.php?id_user=%@&user_email=%@&user_f_name=%@&user_l_name=%@&user_mobile=%@", iduser, email, fName, lName, mobileText]];

NSMutableURLRequest *request=[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];

[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:queue completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {

    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"Error,%@", [error localizedDescription]);

    } else {

        // Do some stuff                        

     }

}];
```

However, this URL would be vulnerable from anyone who finds the URL to just enter any data they want through a web browser, right?

How would I secure these requests so that someone can't type that URL with their own parameters into an address bar?

Comment: it's a post. typing it into the address bar won't help, because that'd cause a get. but faking a post is pretty easy anyways, basically there's NOTHING you can do to prevent someone from accessing that url, because by definition that url has to be open to the entire web, because you can't tell where your legit users will be coming from. You'll have to add some kind of authentication system

Comment: but even that doesn't help completely, because nothing will stop someone from observing data between their device and your server, and replicating what gets sent.

Comment: Employ some sort of token system which is verified server side, however it is as @MarcB said, you can't prevent someone watching and replicating.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it would be to make your PHP API a HTTPS connection, requiring the correct authorization header to perform the POST request. You pass in an authorization header like this:

```
//Auth header
NSString *authStr= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@:%@",usernameOfAdmin,passwordOfAdmin];
NSData *authData = [authStr dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
NSString *authValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Basic %@", [authData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:NSDataBase64EncodingEndLineWithLineFeed]];
[request setValue:authValue forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
```

Then, you could have admin credentials that are required for every POST request. And you could even use an encryption algorithm to make sure your iOS users don't get a hold of the username & password. When a proper sign up is performed from your iOS app, you would use these credentials. Someone else accessing your PHP API would not know the username and password.